# Replacing existing SSL cert on RHEL5/Apache2.2.3

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, redhat

My existing SSL cert is about to expire so I need to replace it with the new one. I have been provided a .cer and .key file. How can I smoothly replace the cert with minimal downtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace the old files with the new ones, and restart the Apache service.

You can find the current certificate and key file locations if you search the ssl vhost config file for `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` settings.

Comment: Thanks! which service would I restart? Apache?

Comment: Apache yes, fixed the answer to make it clearer.